# Translate country name into other language

Tags: java, locale

I searched for a solution, but I have not found any.

I have this kind of information:

```
String locale = "en_GB";
String country = "Japonia"; //It means Japan in polish
```

I need to translate the country name "Japonia" into language indicated in string locale, so "Japan". Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It's possible, but you'll have to provide the translation. Java doesn't come with all countries translated in all languages, if that's your question.

Comment: `System.out.printf("%s %s%n", Locale.JAPAN.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH), Locale.JAPAN.getDisplayCountry(Locale.forLanguageTag("pl-PL")));`

Comment: I stand corrected :-)

Comment: @JBNizet In case you ever wondered exactly why the JRE is 50+ meg now...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I stole your comment and made an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191182/5221149) out of it.

Comment: @Andreas My comment was exactly that (a comment), your answer is an answer... very nice. :)

Comment: Amazing! But... PSA: to anyone who copy pastes Elliott's snippet and gets an error, before counting parentheses like the idiot I am, just remove the gremlin non-printable characters before the set of closing parentheses. I suppose it's too late to edit the comment. It's too important, it will be referenced for decades. Where is the request form to ask for a for a direct fix in the database? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you know both the input language and the desired output language, an alternative approach - iterate the `Locale`(s) on the system using [`Locale.getAvailableLocales()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales--), test if the country name matches from the desired *in* `Locale` - if so display it in the desired output `Locale` using [`getDisplayCountry(Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry-java.util.Locale-)

```
String country = "Japonia";
Locale outLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en_GB");
Locale inLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("pl-PL");
for (Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    if (l.getDisplayCountry(inLocale).equals(country)) {
        System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry(outLocale));
        break;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Japan
```

And if you modify the `outLocale` like

```
Locale outLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("es-SP");
```

you get

```
Japón
```

Comment: Have another small problem and you might know how to solve it.
I need to translate the country that in the name has polish characters, eg.: Włochy (means Italy). I read from file properly with encoding Cp1250, but it does not find the translation.

Answer (score 10):

*(Answer based on [comment by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190906/translate-country-name-into-other-language/44191182#comment75395973_44190906))*

The Java Runtime Library doesn't have a translation API, but the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class can be used to get the name of any country in any language, as long as you know the [ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements), and the [ISO 639 alpha-2 or alpha-3 language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#Partial_ISO_639_table).

Example for country `Japan`:

```
Locale countryJapan = new Locale.Builder().setRegion("JP"/*Japan*/).build();
Locale langEnglish  = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en"/*English*/).build();
Locale langPolish   = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("pl"/*Polish*/).build();
Locale langJapanese = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ja"/*Japanese*/).build();
Locale langItalian  = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("it"/*Italian*/).build();
System.out.println(countryJapan.getDisplayCountry(langEnglish));
System.out.println(countryJapan.getDisplayCountry(langPolish));
System.out.println(countryJapan.getDisplayCountry(langJapanese));
System.out.println(countryJapan.getDisplayCountry(langItalian));
```

*Output*

```
Japan
Japonia
日本
Giappone
```

Comment: This does not work for all languages (for example Czech).

Comment: @James In what way doesn't it work? And if the `Locale` display values are incorrect, you should file a bug for Java.

Comment: If I try your approach to translate language from the example into Czech, I get English version instead. Tried it for some other languages as well, for many this does the same.

Comment: @James So the internationalization team responsible for the Czech language haven't provided translations. As I said: File a bug.

Comment: There si much more langauges that are not suuported this way. That means your answer is incorrect when you say "Locale class can be used to get the name of any country in any language".

Comment: Where do you find the list of languages where the getDisplayCountry(inLocale) function actually provides a translation?

In my opinion someone really messed up when they made this. The fallback should either have been wrapped in it's own method or be disabled via a control variable. Otherwise you have no clue what sort of quality you get from the translation feature unless you try every possible combination of valid locales translated to your language.

Comment: @James did you use the right code for Czech language? the iso-2 code is `cs` and by testing the above code I get `Japonsko`.

Comment: @рüффп `Japonsko` is correct, but sadly I don't really remember what was the problem or what I did three years ago. Sorry :)

Comment: @Erveron I tested better on my side and I arrive to the conclusion that before Java 9 the translations does not always work (tested with e.g lang='bg', lang='cs', lang='kk') and with my local Java 11 it works now for a larger set of language. By the date of the post, you probably did not have the same java version as now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a translation API. Like [Microsoft's](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx) or [Google's](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/).