# Translate english country name into french (API 19)

Tags: android

So I have a little problem that I can't resolve. I need to translate a country name in english to french but I can't do that with API 19. I have read a similar topic but the answer only works for API > 19.

I have checked libraries but I can't find one that fits to my problem and there's not so many about that.

**EDIT :** Code that doesn't work under API 21 :

```
String country = "Japonia";
Locale outLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en_GB");
Locale inLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("pl-PL");
for (Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    if (l.getDisplayCountry(inLocale).equals(country)) {
        System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry(outLocale));
        break;
    }
}
```

Taken from : [Translate country name into other language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190906/translate-country-name-into-other-language)

**EDIT 2 :**

I add the dependenccy from apache but how to use ?

```
LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeString)
```

**EDIT 3**

I used the line above but this doesnt work... I used it with "brazil" but it returned an exception.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3):

It is because `Locale.forLanguageTag()` was added in API level 21.

Try this:

1. Add Apache Commons Lang packet by adding this to build.gradle:

   `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'`
2. Use this function instead:

   `LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeString)`

Comment: Can you explain exactly what I need to do ... ?